# HyperLink problem under Panel within UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

The HyperLink under Panel within UpdatePanel is not clickable. When HyperLink is moved from sub panel to UpdatePanel, everything is good. Here is my code -

Page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="p" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 ...
 <some:UserControl ID="uc" runat="server" />
 ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

SomeUserControl:

```
<asp:Panel ID="p" runat="server">
 ...
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hlExportFile" runat="server" />
 ...
</asp:Panel>
```

Would be glad to hear any solution. Thanks ahead!

Comment: Problem is found - internal panel was just disabled...

Answer (score 0):

You Panel needs an ID.

Comment: I dont' think so, because everything is working good, only problem with that link. Also, when link is moved outside from panel wrapper, the problem disappearing